# Angular JS - Multiple ngrepeat and filters issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with two ng-repeat and a custom filter. This is my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="L in prontoSoccorsoLista"><a href="" ng-click="azione = L.prontoSoccorso; setLabel(L.prontoSoccorso)">{{L.prontoSoccorso}}</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="prontosoccorso" ng-repeat="PS in prontoSoccorso | myFilter:azione" >
    data to show not important
</div>
```

JS

```
.filter('myFilter', function () {
return function (items, search) {
    var result = [];
    console.log(search);
    angular.forEach(items, function(friendData){
        if(friendData.prontoSoccorso == search) {
            result.push(friendData);
        } else if(search == undefined) {
            result.push(friendData);
        }
    });
    return result;

}
});
```

I have to set the value of azione. Whitout ngrepeat on the list I can succesfully set "azione" and catch the correct value of "search" in filter. This is the example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="azione = 1; setLabel('ps1')">{{ps1}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="azione = 2; setLabel('ps2')">{{ps2}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="azione = 3; setLabel('ps3')">{{ps3}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I insert ngrepeat and try to set "azione", in filter it returns me the value of "search" as "undefined". How can I resolve??

Comment: Scope problem. Search for the so-called "dot rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myFilter:azione refers to $scope.azione, while the ng-click doesn't

Try to make a function in your controller:

```
$scope.setAzione = function (L) {
              if (L.prontoSoccorso) {
                  $scope.azione = object.prontoSoccorso;
              }
          }
```

and then call

```
ng-click="setAzione(L)"
```